# Leer continuamente archivo de texto cada vez que se detecta que existe la ruta c#

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando un programa en el cuál necesito leer un archivo de texto cada vez que se guarde en una ruta

Comment: ?? pero cual es la pregunta, que llevas de codigo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para monitorear una carpeta antes eventos con archivo puedes usar la clase `FileSystemWatcher`

[FileSystemWatcher Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.5)

entonces defines

```
using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
{
    watcher.Path = @"c:\..."; //la carpeta que quiere controlar
    watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

    watcher.Changed += OnChanged;

    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

asignando el evento `changed` tendras el evento cuando se grabe una modificacion

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e){
    //codigo
}
```

Por supuesto tienes otros eventos que puede utilizar

Comment: Ojo, FileSystemWatcher tiene problemas cuando son muchos los archivos nuevos o existentes en la carpeta.

Comment: si puede ser, pero mas que nada este tipo de problemas se relaciona con el lockeo de los archivos al queres trabajarlo en los eventos

Comment: Nosotros tuvimos muchos problemas con esta forma de trabajar alguna vez, y no por el bloqueo de archivos, si no por la cantidad. Arriba de 50 tronaba la cosa. Decidimos hacer una rutina (servicio de windows) que se ejecutara cada cierto tiempo y procesara los archivos. Nuevamente, solo es una advertencia, la solución propuesta me parece adecuada para cierto nivel..